# How can the label of the group of a new field in the "Update quotation line" dialog called from the accounts receivable parameters be customized?

Tags: dialog, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to insert in Accounts Receivable-> Settings -> Accounts Receivable Parameters (in form `CustParameters`) a new group with a new parameter field in the dialog of function *Update quotation line*.

[image: Screenshot of CustParameters form]

When button **Update Quotation Line** is clicked, it opens a dialog.

I inserted a new field, I modified method `getFieldDescripion` in class `SalesQuotationToLineField`.

This works, I have the new parameter, but I do not have a **Group** .

I want a group with a label like in the following screenshot, but with my label (field-Label). What do I have to change to achieve this?

[image]

Thanks all!

enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you added a new field to the dialog "Update sales quotation line" that can be called from form `CustParameters` and now you want to change the label of the group of this new field.

To do this, you have to overwrite method `fieldGroupLabel` of class `SalesQuotationToLineField` and add a `switch` similar to method `getFieldDescription` to test for the new field and return a custom label in that case. This overwritten method will be called by method `dialog` in class `SalesPurchTableToLineParametersForm`.

The overwritten `fieldGroupLabel` should look similar to the following example:

```
public FieldLabel fieldGroupLabel()
{
    FieldLabel ret;

    ret = super();

    switch (this.parmFieldId())
    {
        case fieldNum(SalesQuotationTable, SalesGroup): // replace this with the new field
            ret = 'My Group label'; // replace this with the id of the label you want to use
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Really thanks @FH-Inway, but I wan't to add a new Group in a Form, I have to insert a new Group in the _dialog_ to open when you clicked on _Update quotation line_ . Thanks for your time!

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer and your question to reflect that your question is about the dialog and not the parameters form itself.

Comment: Do you can an example ? 
Who will call this method? Very thanks!